# How to stack notifications in android correctly?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

This is my current android code:

```
notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
notification.setContentTitle(notifyFromName);
notification.setContentText(notifyMsg);

if (!msgIsProj) {
    String followText = notifyMsg + " you!";
    notification.setContentText(followText);
    notification.setGroup(GROUP_KEY_FOLLOWERS);
} else {

    notification.setContentText(notifyMsg + " " + notifyItemName);
    notification.setGroup(GROUP_KEY_PROJECTS);
}
notification.setTicker(getString(R.string.titlePushNotify));
notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pushnotify);
notification.setGroupSummary(true);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000,
                              newIntentMsg, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
notification.setAutoCancel(true);
manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

if (notifyMsg != null && !notifyMsg.equals("")) {

    manager.notify(0, notification.build());
}
```

As you can see I added `setGroup` and `setGroupSummary` - However, I see in android docs that I have to also, add a summary notification. A little confused of how I do that and if so how do I call the addLine - where does it pull the info from? [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/stacks.html)

If anyone knows how I can implement it or an example would be great!